# What are ports in gabconfig output in Veritas cluster

Tags: version-control

What does the below a and h mean from the out put of "gabconfig -a" in Vertias Cluster

gabconfig -a

Port a
Port h

Answer (score 1):

Port    Function

---

```
a    gab driver

b    I/O fencing (designed to guarantee data integrity)

d    ODM (Oracle Disk Manager)

f    CFS (Cluster File System)

h    VCS (VERITAS Cluster Server: high availability daemon)

o    VCSMM driver (kernel module needed for Oracle and VCS interface)

q    QuickLog daemon

v    CVM (Cluster Volume Manager)

w    vxconfigd (module for cvm)
```

Answer (score 0):

GAB is a Global Atomic Broadcast kernel driver in Veritas Cluster Server that helps multiple cluster nodes communicate to each other about the presence or absence (aka cluster membership) to each other. GAB uses the kernel module LLT (Low Latency Transport).

GAB has the notion of pre-defined ports that are used for pre-defined services. For example, the port "a" is used by GAB itself, the port "h" is used by the "had" (high availability) daemon. If the "had" daemon dies, the port gets closed which is how GAB learn that the "had" daemon has died.

See the Veritas Cluster Server user's guide for more juicy details:
https://origin-symwisedownload.symantec.com/resources/sites/SYMWISE/content/live/DOCUMENTATION/2000/DOC2389/en_US/vcs_users_linux.pdf